# Adding 2 Numbers following onChange in form - Javascript

Tags: javascript, onchange

I want to do something very simple!!

I have a form... I want to enter 2 numbers and have a box that updates with the sum of the two numbers I've inputted.

Unfortunately - the code I'm using seems to see the values as text and just puts them next to each other... so 5+1 becomes 51...

Here is the code:

`

```
function av(avSelect)
{
var one=avSelect.form.one.value;
var two=avSelect.form.two.value;
var avvy=one+two;
avSelect.form.avvy.value=avvy;
}
</script>

<form name="5">
<br>
Adding<input type="number" id="avvy" value="">
Put a number in:<input type="number" id="one" OnChange="av(this)">
Put a number in:<input type="number" id="two" OnChange="av(this)">
</form>`
```

Comment: `var avvy=parseInt(one)+parseInt(two);`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var one = parseFloat(avSelect.form.one.value);
var two = parseFloat(avSelect.form.two.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var one  = parseInt(avSelect.form.one.value);
    var two  = parseInt(avSelect.form.two.value);
    var avvy = one+two;
    avSelect.form.avvy.value=avvy;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've juste made the solution for you: 
http://jsfiddle.net/c2dJt/
For the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '.change', function(){
        var number = parseFloat($('#one').val()) + parseFloat($('#two').val());
        $('#avvy').val(number);
    });
});
```

Fot the HTML:

```
<form name="5">
Adding<input type="number" id="avvy" value="">
Put a number in:<input type="number" id="one" class="change">
Put a number in:<input type="number" id="two" class="change">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is added as a string and not as an integer. The `parseInt()` function parses a string and returns an integer. This should fix the issue

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        function av(avSelect) {
            var one=avSelect.form.one.value;
            var two=avSelect.form.two.value;
            var avvy=parseInt(one)+parseInt(two);
            avSelect.form.avvy.value=avvy;
        }
</script>
```